# How to get the text of all options in a select input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get all the text content of all options comma separated using jQuery? The value of the select field itself is only the value of the currently selected option.

```js
const foo = $('#selector').val()
document.write(foo)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want something like this as a result

```
Option 1, Option 2,Option 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute `each` function over your `options`, push them into an `array` and then execute `join` function.

```js
var collected = [];
var foo = $('#selector option').each(function() {
  collected.push($(this).text());
}); 

console.log(collected.join(','));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you. Can you explain why my title *Look at this code snippet* was removed?  Just to improve the way I'm formatting my answer.

Comment: Because it was not little, it was formatted like a title, because it started with `#` and, frankly, didn't add much to the answer, so while I was at it I removed it altoghether. If you restore it without the formatting I won't remove it again, though. Up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = []
$('select > option').each((i, {innerHTML}) => arr.push(innerHTML))

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Here i have queried the options of the select which gave me an array of elements. 
I looped through those elements and pushed their respective `innerHTML` to an `arr`.

Use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to reduce that array to a string :-)

Comment: Give me a chance, was just writing it up.

Comment: True! Apologies for the snap.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow simple logic:

1. Loop over the `<option>`element
2. Get the text from each `<option>`element and push it to an array.
3. Stringify the array with `toString()` and get the values as comma separated.

```js
var optionsArray = [];
//loop over each option element
var optionElements = $('#selector option').each(function() {
  //push the text of option in the array
  optionsArray.push($(this).text());
}); 
//stringify the array to get the comma seperated result
console.log(optionsArray.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selector" id="selector">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#selector option:selected").text();
```

Will give you selected text instead of the value.

Comment: What about the "comma separated" part?